# How to convert Bounding Box coordinates to Yolo Coordinates with Python?

Tags: python, pytorch, yolo, yolov5

I need to convert the coordinates. I have this format `<left> <top> <width> <height>`
And I need `x_center y_center width height` in this format. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center is just the middle of your bounding box. So just add half of the bounding box width or height to yout top-left coordinate. Width and height remain unchanged

```
x_center = left + width / 2
y_center = top + height / 2
```

Comment: And if I want to normalize coordinates 
x_center = (left + w/2) / w_img
y_center = (top + h/2) / h_img
w = w / w_img
h = h / h_img
It's correct ?